# React Native Hooks - dinamically create an array of refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

### Introduction

I have an array of data which contains objects with unique ids.

I am trying to create as many references as neccessary. For example, if the array have 4 elements then I will create 4 references. Each reference has to be contained in an array and also, I need to associate it to the unique id of the object.

Here is what I am trying to do in "pseudocode":

### Pseudocode

```
 data = [{id: "10i3298yfrcd", ...}, {id: "y48hfeucldnjs", ...}]

 references = data.map(({id}) => useRef(null))
```

### Problem

I don't know how to associate each created reference to its respective object id (just to access the references like with an array of alphanumeric indexes, or something like this)...

Also, I get an error when creating the references this way:

> React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by %s. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

So I suppose this is not a valid form to create references dynamically.

Any ideas how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Problem here is that React Hooks can only be called at the top level in functional components. You are calling `useRef` hook inside a callback function which is not allowed. You should visit the link in your question to read more about the rules of using hooks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is how you can create a useRef depending of data.lenght

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from react;

const ArrayInputs = () => {
    const inputRef = useRef([]);
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect( () => {
        let data = ['Name', 'Age', 'Gender'];
        inputRef.current = new Array(data.length);
        setData(data);
    }, []);
    
    useEffect( () => {
        //Example of using inputRef
        if(data.length !== 0) {
            inputRef.current[data.length - 1].focus();
        }
    }, [data]);
    
    return(
        <View>
            {data.map( (element, i) => <TextInput ref = {el => inputRef.current[i] = el} />)}
        </View>
    
    );

}
```